# Refresh view controller after tab is selected

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented a `UITabBarController` for iOS.  When I click on the third tab, I need to programmatically go to the first tab .. this works fine with

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

But when the tab time is selected and the appropriate view controller appears, I need to first refresh it.  I have tried calling `didSelectViewController`, but that only seems to work when the tab is pressed.  I need to call a method after the focus of the view appears.

Comment: What about the lifecycle-Method viewWillAppear ?

Comment: @dealloc - it does not get called, breakpoint missed

Comment: viewWillAppear always get called when you switch between tabs of tabbarcontroller